# How to change the string of an element in JQuery to a symbol character?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

`$("#third_param").text('&epsilon;')` gives me the following [image: "epsilon"], how do I fix this such that it shows the actual ε character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of `.text`:

```
$("#third_param").html('&epsilon;');
```

`&epsilon;` is an HTML entity, so you have to pass it through the HTML parser.